# em dash in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Does anyone know how to make the em dash appear in IE7?

I have tried to use the `IE9.js` file but it doesn't appear to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In its present form, the question does not make sense. There is no particular problem with em dash in IE 7. From the comments, it seems that your real problem might be with generated content, or something. Please edit the question to reflect the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just type it out?

In HTML:

```
&mdash; or &#8212;
```

And in CSS:

```
content:"\2014"
```

Comment: I have to make it work by importing it via css. div#algemene_informatie h2:after{
 content: ' — ';

Comment: I just edited my answer, which answers your question :)

Comment: IE7 does not support generated content.

Comment: So I suppose, I'll have to do it with Modernizr? But then I wonder what do I have to put in the ie7.css file that I'm going to make? will content:" div#algemene_informatie h2:after {content:"\2014";} do the trick?

Comment: AFAIK, Modernizr just _detects_ features, but does not polyfill them (the only exception is built-in HTML5Shiv).

Comment: Yeah, so if I make an additional polyfill in an external css sheet, will I be able to make it work?

Comment: Polyfilling generated content would require full-fledged script parsing of stylesheets. Such parsing would be not only slow, but also would result in nontrivial issues related to possible inconsistencies of such parser compared with native CSS parsers of browsers. It's better to drop support for IE7 as for at least such inessential aspects as generating em dash, or use a quick and straightforward JS workaround involving generating real elements as I've described in my answer.

Comment: Point of interest: IE9.js is a feature polyfill, and a damned good one, but even Dean Edwards is giving less and less attention to the library. It hasn't been updated since Apr 30, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
// Support IE7, which doesn't support :before pseudo selectors
*zoom: expression(
  function(t) {
    t.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1';
    t.innerHTML = "&mdash; " + t.innerHTML;
  }(this)
);
```

Comment: It makes sense to take into account that IE expressions feature is nonstandard/invalid.

Comment: Can't I just use Modernizr with a custom build for generatedcontent? If yes, how will I have to adjust my css selector?

Comment: Modernizr won't automatically polyfill support for generated content… it will only tell you that support exists or that it doesn't. IE9.js polyfills the ability, but if you want to avoid adding IE9.js this CSS will work instead. @MaratTanalin, yes, it's nonstandard/invalid, and only evaluates in IE7 (the `*` before the property name keeps the property from being evaluated by other browsers). Yes, it's a hack, but it's a hack that takes only 6 lines in your CSS vs. adding an entire library to as a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

For IE of versions older than 8, generate real elements via JavaScript and make them contain real content equivalent to content of `:before`/`:after` generated pseudoelement:

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example'),
    span    = document.createElement('span');

span.innerHTML = '&mdash;'
example.appendChild(span);
```

And then attach the `span` element with same styles as your `:before`/`:after` generated pseudoelement.

By the way, consider dropping support for such ancient IE version as IE7. Actually, it's time to consider dropping support for IE8 already. ;-)

Comment: +1 for dropping IE7 support, although most projects I've worked for large corporations still carry a "IE7 support" stipulation. Annoying as heck, but I think it's because a lot of corps still run XP, and some IT depts have been lazy :-p It's not the worst requirement in the world though… At least it's not IE6 :-p